# QTimer doesn't trigger

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots, qtimer

I'm trying to get the `QTimer` running, but it never triggers.
I found some other questions about the timer, but the problem was always the timer being out of scope. This is not the case in my small example:

I create the timer in a custom `QMainWindow`, this is the .h file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QTimer>

class MyMainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT;

private:
    QTimer *mainTimer;

public slots:
    void timerUpdate();

public:
    MyMainWindow();
};
```

This is the .cpp file:

```
#include "MyMainWindow.h"

MyMainWindow::MyMainWindow() {
    QMainWindow();
    mainTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(mainTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    mainTimer->start(1000);
    std::cout << "Timer created.\n";
}

void MyMainWindow::timerUpdate() {
    std::cout << "test";
}
```

Finally, this is my main.cpp:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include "MyMainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MyMainWindow mmw;
    mmw.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

When I execute this code, I only get "Timer created." and never "test".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're connecting to `SLOT(update())`, but your function is called `timerUpdate`.

Using more modern [Qt 5 signal-slot connection syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), that would never have happened and you'd get an error at compile-time. You should prefer using that.

Comment: Great catch and thanks for the tip! I changed the line to the following:


      connect(mainTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MyMainWindow::timerUpdate);


now all the timer events seem to get queued up and are only executed when I close the window.

Comment: Try flushing the output: `std::cout << "test" << std::endl;` or `std::flush`

Comment: ahhh, Im a noob :) Thank you!